# Android Studio USB Debugging Google Play Services Out Of Date

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, usb-debugging

I'm using Android Studio 1.2 and I'm  trying to run an app (that requires Google Maps) using **USB Debugging**. My phone is running Android 4.1.2 (API 16 - Sony Xperia T).

On Android Studio I was able to run successfully the app using Android 5.0.1 (API 21). However, using USB Debugging I get this error *"Google Play Services Out Of Date, Requires 713.... but found 65...."* (dots represent some numbers). **My device has the latest Google Play Version.**

In Android Studio under Project Structure, I've selected **compile SDK version**: Android 5.0.1 (API 21) and **target SDK version**: Android 4.1.2 (API 16).

Am I missing something? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thank you all!

**UPDATE**
This is the logcat

```
05-05 15:20:49.436    6003-6003/com.myapp.testapp D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
05-05 15:20:58.546    6003-6003/com.myapp.testapp I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: access denied from Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil; to field Landroid/app/Notification;.extras
05-05 15:20:58.546    6003-6003/com.myapp.testapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve instance field 16
05-05 15:20:58.546    6003-6003/com.myapp.testapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x54 at 0x00b3
05-05 15:20:58.546    6003-6003/com.myapp.testapp E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
05-05 15:20:58.546    6003-6003/com.myapp.testapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 25 (Landroid/app/AppOpsManager;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;
05-05 15:20:58.546    6003-6003/com.myapp.testapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000e
05-05 15:20:58.546    6003-6003/com.myapp.testapp I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzh
05-05 15:20:58.546    6003-6003/com.myapp.testapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 523: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
05-05 15:20:58.546    6003-6003/com.myapp.testapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
05-05 15:20:58.556    6003-6003/com.myapp.testapp W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7327000 but found 6599036
```

Comment: Post your logcat. Your error has something to do with your device's  or your project's GooglePlayServices version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your device should have the latest [Google Play Services](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms)
2. Your project should have the latest Google Play Services

Gradle configuration:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
}
```

3. Use [GoogleApiAvailability](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability.html) class to check for this on the device

Comment: 1. How can I update to the latest Google Play Services version in my mobile? Because I can't find any results on Google Play.

2. I have already included this in my project's Gradle.

Comment: You indeed have the 6599036 version and not the required 7327000 on your device (form your logcat).

Comment: You should have a more complete implementation of the Google Play Services, and check for its availability and version: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability.html

Comment: I understand that my mobile's Google Play Services version is older than the latest. Should I change my project's code, or is there any way to update my mobile's Google Play Services version?

Comment: I updated my answer with GoogleApiAvailability class. Use it or at least use https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context)

Comment: Thank you, I missed **GoogleApiAvailability** !